# QProgressBar on QStatusBar : how to remove the 2 little vertical lines on either side of the QprogressBar?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I add a QProgressBar following a QLabel to the QStatusBar by the following code ,but the QProgressBar is lined with 2 little vertical lines .
I wonder how to remove the 2 vertical lines ?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(800, 600)

        self.lb=QLabel('finding resource   ')

        self.pb = QProgressBar()
        self.pb.setRange(0, 0)
#        self.pb.setTextVisible(False)

        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.lb)
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.pb, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ui = MainWindow()
    ui.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This may be an artefact from the current style, can you tell what `QStyle` you are using (or your platform if you haven't specified one)?  A picture would be useful as well.

Comment: Its just the Windows style which can be changed as follows:


self.statusBar().setStyleSheet("QStatusBar::item {border: none;}")